Bridge edge loop problem
Hello im trying to use bridge edge loop to make a hole but instead it covers it entirely.

I have tried it on the other side and it works fine.


Bridge Edge Loop is used to connect between two loops not to make holes.
If you want to make a hole then inset the face in which you want hole then select the inset face and then right click (in edit mode) use Loop Tool > Circle then delete the face

Of course you can make holes with Bridge Edge Loops: hole in cube.  Actually in cases like the one shown in my image it is my preferred method. It's all a matter of having the right geometry for that so I guess something is messed up there when in some places it worked and in others not.
